# MassTransit Send to Existing Exchange

Tags: masstransit

So I'm adding MassTransit to an existing project that was just using the RMQ client before.

I'm trying to create a send only bus that binds to an existing exchange. However, when I try to send the message I get an error about the exchange type being "fanout" but the existing type is "topic" and I'm not sure how to specify that it should either be "topic" or that it shouldn't try to create the exchange at all and just use what is there.

Topology: 'import' (exchange) -> 'import' (queue)

Setup:

```cs
    Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(
                    cfg =>
                    {
                        cfg.UseNLog();

                        var host = cfg.Host(serverName, vhost,
                            options =>
                            {
                                options.Username(userName);
                                options.Password(password);
                            });                    
                    });
```

Execution:

```cs
    var ep = bus.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri($"rabbitmq://{userName}:{password}@{serverName}/{vhost}/{queue}")).Result;

                    ep.Send<ImportMessage>(CastMessage<ImportMessage>(message),
                        cfg =>
                        {

                            cfg.SetRoutingKey("import");
                        }).Wait();
```

Command :

```cs
    public class ImportMessage 
    {
        public ImportMessage()
        {
            Parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        }

        public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Parameters { get; set; }
        public string Endpoint { get; set; }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public DateTime Expiration { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure the publish topology for a message contract using:

```
Bus.Factory.CreateUsingXxx(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Publish<YourMessageType>(x => x.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Topic);
});
```

Then, when you publish your message, it will use that exchange type. You can also change the name of the entity using the message topology:

```
cfg.Message<YourMessageType>(x => x.SetEntityName("your-exchange"));
```

That will specify the exchange name for the type.

There is a [sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Direct) that shows direct exchange support, topic exchanges are similar on the client side.

Comment: So I thought publish was for events while send was for commands, or does it not really matter?

Comment: While you're right, that's true. You're using a topic exchange with a specific name, so that's why you use publish in this case to send messages with MassTransit. Semantically, you're correct. Programatically, this is how you do it.